# Jbpm 5 form processing

Tags: jbpm

I am developing an application using Jbpm 5.4. I deploy my workflow using JBoss Guvnor. I create a task form for each user task.I mapped user input outputs in guvnor. Now i want to complete task form with user inputs.

I want to know how jbpm console automatically identify form inputs and complete task with results. I tried with CompleteWithResults() method , but no luck.

Please can anyone solve this problem?

Here i have edited my code as you request;

```
try {
        String first=request.getParameter("fname_first");
        String second=request.getParameter("lname_first");
        TaskService taskService = JBPMApi.getTaskService();

        Map<String, Object> params=new HashMap<String, Object>();
        params.put("fname_first", first);
        params.put("lname_first", second);

        taskService.start(169, "krisv");

        taskService.completeWithResults(169, "krisv", params);
}catch (Exception e){
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: paste Code you are using to complete task.

Comment: try {
   String first=request.getParameter("fname_first");
   String second=request.getParameter("lname_first");
   TaskService taskService = JBPMApi.getTaskService();

   Map<String, Object> params=new HashMap<String, Object>();
   params.put("fname_first", first);
   params.put("lname_first", second);

   taskService.start(169, "krisv");
   
   taskService.completeWithResults(169, "krisv", params);
   
  } catch (Exception e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

Comment: Is there any method completeWI() also. I don't have source code right now. try to run this in transaction.

Comment: I am new to Jbpm 5.4 , as i know there are only these two methods to complete task -- Complete() and completeWithResults()

Comment: did you try this in transaction? try completing WorkItem.

Comment: I am going to do this another way. I am going to access task form via Rest api and complete the task. It works fine for already registered users in jbpm console. It gives an error for new users. Can u tell me how i add a new user for jbpm console?

Comment: There is user.properties/role.properties files you can add new user there and redeploy.

Comment: I already added users for that files(bpm-installer/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/configuration/user.properties, roles.properties)                                                   
sales-rep=sales-rep
fathima=fathima
Following is my roles.properties file                                                                sales-rep=admin,manager,user,sales
fathima=admin,Marketing                                              but no luck??? fathima can not log into jbpm console, but sales-rep can

Comment: Once u redeploy app, check in jBPM database if user got inserted or not? Tables People* and Organization*

Comment: I solved the problem, I didn't add user role to roles.properties file.  Thanks Neeraj

Comment: It is inserting, but when I am trying to complete task via Rest api following error occured.                                                               ERROR [org.drools.persistence.SingleSessionCommandService] (Thread-83) Could not commit session: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.jbpm.process.instance.impl.ProcessInstanceImpl.setProcess(ProcessInstanceImpl.java:62) [jbpm-flow-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]                                     Do you have any idea?